# How can i make my square button and spinner the same height?

Tags: android, android-layout

usecase:

I want a spinner with a clickable, squared image-button to the right of it, on the same row, with the button the same height as the spinner.

There was first a problem getting an imagebutton to be square, which i solved reading this thread: [How do I keep the aspect ratio on image buttons in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656986/how-do-i-keep-the-aspect-ratio-on-image-buttons-in-android)

I now have them on the same row and with the icon square and resized, but not quite to the size of the spinner, the 9-patch (i think) of the spinner creates some sort of padding around it and my image uses that to set its height, so that it looks like this: 
[image]

If someone can help me out here it would be greatly appreciated. Layout-xml below:

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/spinnerRow"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  style="@style/horizontalLayout" android:gravity="top"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:paddingTop="5dp">            
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/spinLayout" style="@style/spinLayout" android:layout_weight="1">
            <Spinner android:id="@+id/locSelect" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:prompt="@string/loc_prompt"></Spinner>
        </LinearLayout>
        <com.karpet.nuba.util.SquareButton
            android:id="@+id/info" android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="top" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:src="@drawable/info"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        </com.karpet.nuba.util.SquareButton>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try to put them on the same layout and set height as match or fill parent

Comment: since you used weight set height to 0dp for both

Comment: then try to play with wait it could work

Comment: w=fill,h= **dp Value** ,orientation = horisontal

Comment: and weight in this case doesn't matter, if problem in height.