# How to align imagebutton with equel width in Linearlayout

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-button

I have linearlayout with 4 imagebutton one after another. In linearlayout with horizontal orientation and provided equal width. Here buttons are aligning properly but the images present in those buttons are not getting aligned properly.

Here is the below code, i have tried and this is how it looks. How do i make the images align properly with correct shape?

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/add_fav_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_share_fb_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_share_all_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/id_whatsapp_btn"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minWidth="0dp"
        android:minHeight="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Updated image, after changing  `android:layout_height="50dp" to  android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting aligned properly"? Are you referring to the stretching?

Answer (score 0):

Your images looks like squared. you are making them stretch way to fill the entire width but you are making them all with height of `50dp`.

Change the height from 50dp to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and they will keep a correct height based on the width. If you want them all to be with height of 50dp, you have two choices:

1. Set the width to 50dp and center them in the parent
2. Create the ["square button"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7979110/4700782)

I don't know if I got the point, if not comment below

Comment: HI, thnks for the reply, i did like that, i have uploaded the new image. still image looks like stretched, i.e horizontally it is stretched more-than vertical.

Comment: @Naruto I'm still seeing the old question :( have you created the square button class?

Comment: @Naruto nothing, now i see the correct one. you want them perfectly squared?

Comment: Yes, if i use padding left, then it works well... but i want them to make it correct square.. is there anyway?, please help

Comment: @Naruto ok, so use my "2." solution :)

Comment: i'll try now, give me few mins, ill get back.. thank you so much,,

Comment: One more thing, if i add .png icons the button stretches, but same svg will work as expected. But svg i'm facing lot of issues due to backward compatibility..

Comment: I feel like, its better to add margin for individual button to look more spacious and cool

Comment: @Naruto the problem with margin will come on different size screens i think.. you sure the icons you are using are squared?

Answer (score 0):

Put all each image button in a relative layout and layout_weight of relativelayout to 1 and layout_width= match_parent

I think this may work ...... or try using imageview instead of imagebutton

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#fff"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/add_fav_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/id_share_fb_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/id_share_all_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/id_whatsapp_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_whatsapp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

Comment: why do we need to include so many relativelayout?. i think its not correct way

Comment: did you try this solution?